# Deleting everything from the stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

So, I am wanting to clear my whole stage. I already searched through the internet, and unfortunately nothing has worked for my situation.

Basically, what I am doing is a somewhat complex maze generator and before I create a new one, I want to get rid of everything I created prior to that. So far, I hear that the best way to remove movieclips from the stage is buy using:

```
while(numChildren > 0)
    removeChildAt(0);
```

However this only works for the current movieclip I call it in, which doesn't include the maze I generated. I just want to get rid of absolutely everything.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking along the right lines, you can use `numChildren` and `removeChildAt` however you need to call them in the scope of the stage:

```
while(stage.numChildren > 0)
{
  stage.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that these days we have access to [removeChildren()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildren%28%29)

Comment: @PixelElephant I'm sorry, I can't find removeChildren()... Could you share the correct link?

Comment: It should be noted that when the current MovieClip will get removed from stage, its stage property will get invalidated, so one has to store it first via `var the_stage:Stage=this.stage;` and use the_stage as reference.

Comment: @loxxy That is the correct link but you may have to change the filter settings by hovering over the "Runtimes" filter in the top left of the screen and change the Flash Player version to 11, as player versions before that do not have access to the removeChildren() function.

Answer (score 5):

To just remove it from the stage:

```
stage.removeChildren();
```

**Just removing clips from stage isn't always equal of removing them from memory**

`removeChildren`, `removeChild` or `removeChildAt` does not actually remove an Sprite or any other DisplayObject from *memory*, it only removes it from the `displaylist`. That means if you create 1000 sprites and add them to the stage (displaylist), and then use `removeChildren` they could still exist in memory (forever). Then you have a memory leak.

To remove it from memory, all objects with a relation to the `displayObject` should be set to null. This includes event listeners and relations from / to `non-displaylist` related objects.

If you want to be sure all related stuff should be gone, just null it and check these things:

- Remove it from the `displaylist` using `removeChild` or `removeChildAt` or removeChildren. (note this can be done from the stage)
- Remove all `eventListeners` that are attached to the clip, or use *weak* event listeners.
- If you used a reference in an Array, Vector, Dictionary or any other object, remove it from the object, set it to null or splice it using Array.splice()
- `setTimeout/setInterval` should be cleared
- Set the `object = null`

You can profile the memory with [Mr Doob stats](https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats) or [performance stats](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/temple/utils/PerformanceStat.html) from the Temple Library. You should see a drop (garbage collection) after a while when removing all clips. After removing multiple times the memory indicator should not be higher.